# Bundle returns incorrect CSS (MVC 4, .NET 4.5)

Tags: css, asp.net-mvc, bundle

We have the following line in our BundleConfig.cs

```
bundles.Add(new StyleBundle("~/css/global").Include("~/assets/css/global.css").Include("~/assets/css/global-custom.css"));
```

This is then used on our layout template like so

```
@Styles.Render("~/css/global")
```

In debug mode, the styles are all correct, as it just puts in links to the flat CSS files, but in release mode the optimisation takes place and we end up with a link like this

```
<link href="/css/global?v=JeCJ-mJfPPBREwlOCYDzyEG1VfJETaOYdJRHLkBLU9w1" rel="stylesheet">
```

But we end up with some style issues on the page.
Searching through the returned CSS shows that there are styles which the bundling has just not included at all. I have tried making the bundle only reference global.css (and not global-custom.css) with the same issue of styles from global.css not coming through.

I have looked at threads with other problems with the bundling and have tried solutions to those problems with no luck, and have not been able to find a similar problem online.

Does anybody know why this might be happening?

Comment: Do you have any minified version for your css?

Comment: @Anup It's not a minified version we are bundling, we don't have a minified version but could produce one. Why do you ask?

Comment: Coz Bundling uses the minified version in the release mode.

Comment: if you have a corresponding minified version for the CSS then the same will be used in release version.

Comment: @Anup It's minified automatically as part of the bundling process by MVC.

Comment: It may will be minified automatically only when it doesn't have a corresponding minified version.

Comment: @Anup You were right, there was a minified version sat there D:
I've deleted it and it's fixed the problem, thanks!